# List files from directory and subdirectories

Tags: r

I have different csv files with the same name (Multy_year_summary.csv) inside different folders as follow:

```
Directory_1
           Folder_1
                   Multy_year_summary.csv
           Folder_2 
                   Multy_year_summary.csv
           Folder_3
                   Multy_year_summary.csv
```

I want to list all .csv files so i tried as follow:

```
list_of_files <- list.files("C:/Users/feder/Directory_1", pattern = "Multy_year_summary.csv$", full.names = T, recursive = T, include.dirs = T)
list_results <- lapply(list_of_files, read.csv)
```

but `list_of_files` is empty so it seems that no files were detected (character(0)).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need `full.names=TRUE` argument in list.files.

Comment: this sounds like a working directory issue, try either appending the path to `list_of_files` or  setting your [working directory](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711843-Working-Directories-and-Workspaces) to `"C:/Users/feder/Directory_1"`

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: R has its own regex syntax. Your regex is Perl-like, which does not work automatically. Usually functions that regex also have a `perl=TRUE` argument to activate Perl-like regex syntax. `list.files()` and `dir()` don't seem to have that argument according to their `?` doc. Study the R regex syntax (link in the `?` doc of `list.files()`) or simply remove the `'$'` from your regex and use plain text. Or take all the files and filter them in a second step with `grepl()` which does accept the `perl=TRUE` argument for Perl-like regex.

Comment: @cymon, how is that a perl regex? (And how does R have its own regex?) It has `$`, which is normal-regex. Other than that, the only issue I see with the pattern is that I'm *inferring* it should end in `\\.csv$` instead of `.csv$`, though that is much more of a technicality than a functional issue. (From `?list.files`, `pattern=` is *"an optional regular expression"*, so `$` is perfectly fine. The only time that `$` would not work is when a function expects *globs* instead of *regexes* ... and `list.files` is not one such function.)

Comment: FedericoGrillo, I suspect this might either be a typo in the filename or perhaps a case issue. Try adding `ignore.case=TRUE` and see if you find it. If not, then I suggest you change to `list.files(..., pattern="\\.csv$")` (all other args as you have them) and see if you find the right filenames in your (potentially long) vector of filenames. (BTW, you should almost always use `full.names=TRUE`, especially when using `recursive=TRUE`.)

Comment: One last comment: before your recent edit, you named the file `Multi_year_summary.csv`, and it erred with *"no such file"*. In the current version, you named the file `Multy_year_summary.csv` (`y` instead of `i`), and you claim `character(0)` instead of an error. I'll restate my guess that this is a typo, but it could be in the filename (`Multi_...`) or perhaps in the directory itself. (I don't think it's a case issue, as windows typically ignores case whether you want it to or not.)